# SQL sum round numbers and count decimal

Tags: mysql, sql, informix

How to sum integers as they are and treat floating numbers as `1`.

From the table given below the expected result is:

```
1 + 1 + 1 + 5 = 8
```

---

```
colum1 colum2

aa        1

bb       0.5

cc      3.66

dd         5
```

Comment: Can you please explain the question further ? How is 3.66 considered as 1 in your request ?

Comment: I've updated the question. Maybe this is readable now. You might take a look @Shrinath

Comment: If the floating point value is 3.00, should that be treated as if it were 3 or as 1?

Answer (score 0):

You can compare each number to its floored value to check if it is a decimal or not, and then use a `case` expression to treat decimals as 1:

```
SELECT CAST(SUM(CASE number WHEN FLOOR(number) THEN number ELSE 1 END) AS INTEGER) 
FROM   mytable;
```